# Problems rendering FontAwesome and Glyphicons in Firefox and Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-awesome, glyphicons

I'm the dev of www.xlent.se and if you try to load the page in IE or FF you'll notice that all icons are replaced by "hex blocks".

The problems only appeared after migrating the project from the development server to the production server. I'm not sure if it's due to caching or MIME-types or something else.

Comment: Try including the original css file from a CDN and check if it still doesn't work: `//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css`

Comment: That made FontAwesome render properly, thanks! Know where to include the bootstrap glyphicons from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your comment it seems that your server doesn't send the right headers.
You could solve this by adding the following to your `.htaccess` file:

```
<FilesMatch ".(ttf|otf|eot|woff)">  
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```

If you load the files (`bootstrap` and `font-awesome`) from a CDN and not from your server use the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Also make sure that you don't load `font-awesome` multiple times. 
Your minified [CSS](https://www.xlent.se/wp-content/cache/minify/000000/M9CvyEnNK9EvLqnMSQUA.css) already contains the `font-awesome` and `bootstrap`.

Comment: Adding the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header solved my problem, thank you. Also, I closed the FilesMatch with </FilesMatch>, not sure if necessary.

Comment: @EmilKantis I forgot the ending tag, added it to the answer.